# Wrong hostname in Atlassian Crucible notification emails

Tags: atlassian-crucible

My Virtual Machine has hostname defined, for instance, mycrucible.
This VM is deployed in the cloud. But this domain name is not registered. Thus, I can access my Crucible installation over IP address only.

When I get notifications from Crucible, all links inside the email have hostname (mycrucible) instead of IP.

Actually, when I installed Crucible, it somehow read this hostname (probably stored somewhere).
My site URL in server settings is changed to IP.

How can I fix that issue? I want to get working emails where links contain IP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem I had is that by default Crucible used site URL as IP. And it was sending emails with machine hostname anyway (Crucible bug!?). I have changed site URL in global server settings manually to my IP and it started to work. Now I get correct links in Crucible emails.